# How to make JQuery and Bootstrap 3 work together in a Google PageSpeed Insights world?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, google-pagespeed

Since Google announced last month that it would be taking page speed and load structure into consideration when ranking websites I`ve spent a considerable amount of time trying to find a way to guarantee JQuery and Bootstrap 3 play nice with each other still.

To prevent css and javascript from page blocking I wrote this code to make sure everything gets loaded at the bottom of a site asynchronously.

```
function loadFirst(filename, filetype) {
    if(filetype == "js") {
        var node = document.createElement('script');
        node.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        node.setAttribute("async", true);
        node.setAttribute("src", filename);
    } else if(filetype == "css") {
        var node = document.createElement("link");
        node.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        node.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        node.setAttribute("href", filename);
    }
    if(typeof node != "undefined") {
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        h.parentNode.insertBefore(node, h);
    }
}

/* Load all CSS first and JS files for your site here. */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    loadFirst("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js", "js");
    loadFirst("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css", "css");
    loadFirst("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js", "js");
    loadFirst("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese", "css");
});
```

But JQuery doesn`t get a chance to finish loading before bootstrap.min.js test for JQuery and fails.  So what I did to partially solve this problem was comment out:

```
//loadFirst("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js", "js");
```

and load it above the javascript via:

```
<script async src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works most of the time but now I want to use JQuery to help me customise a Bootstrap carousel by placing this code inside the window.addEventListener event to make it auto start:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000,
    pause: false
})
```

but that generates:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

And I`m at my wits end trying to find a way to guarantee JQuery is fully loaded before my subsequent Bootstrap custom code starts running.  If this kind of code is too complicated to write in a couple of lines of code are there any libraries that deal with this problem already?

Here is what I got working sofar:
http://jsfiddle.net/2g4tbe72/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a script loader such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  Here's some jQuery specific info http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html to get you going.